# error: expected class-name before '{' token { ^

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I keep getting this
error: expected class-name before '{' token
 {
 ^ line 15
what does this error mean exactly? Im attempting to inherit the controller class that has a function that I need to call in form1's cpp.

```
#ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H


#include <QDialog>
#include "controller.h"



namespace Ui {
class form1 ;
}

class form1 : public QDialog, public controller
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit form1(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~form1();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::form1 *ui;
};

#endif // FORM1_H
```

the controller class

```
#include "controller.h"
#include "ui_controller.h"

controller::controller(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::controller) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    show(1); }

void controller::show(int x) {
    if(x==1)
    {
        myform1 = new form1(this);
        myform1->show();
    }
    if(x==2)
    {
        myform2 = new form2(this);
        myform2->show();
    }
    if(x==3)
    {
        myform3 = new form3(this);
        myform3->show();
    } }

controller::~controller() {
    delete ui; }
```

controller.h:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <form1.h>
#include <form2.h>
#include <form3.h>

namespace Ui {
class controller;
}

class controller : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    form1 * myform1;
    form2 * myform2;
    form3 * myform3;

    void show(int x);
    explicit controller(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~controller();

private:
    Ui::controller *ui;
};

#endif // CONTROLLER_H
```

Comment: Is `controller` in the global namespace?

Comment: See my edit, the problem was indeed a circular include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you have a circular include issue, meaning `controller.h` includes, either directly or indirectly, `form1.h`.

EDIT: Change the include I was talking about to a forward declaration - you don't need the full definition of `form1`:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_H
#define CONTROLLER_H

#include <QWidget>
class form1;
class form2;
class form3;

namespace Ui {
class controller;
}

class controller : public QWidget
{
//.................
//.................
```